# making 3 select tag with php and ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax

this is my first day with AJAX, is easier than i imagine , i make one select tag that open another select tag and it work fine
that is the code...

*test.php*

```
<?php
require'models/category.php';
$object=new category;
$rows=$object->display_category();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showUser(str) {
  if (str=="") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="choose a category";
    return;
  } 
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
      document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","getTest.php?q="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">

<option value="">Select a category:</option>

<?php
foreach($rows as $row){
$row['cat_name']=str_replace('-',' ',$row['cat_name']);

echo'<option value="'.$row['cat_id'].'">'.$row['cat_name'].'</option>';
}
?>
</select>
</form>
<br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>category info will be listed here.</b></div>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is getTest.php

```
<?php
require'models/connection.php';
$q = $_GET['q'];

$query="select * from category where parent_id='".$q."' ";

$stmt=$db->prepare($query);    
$stmt->execute();

    $result=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);   
?>
<form action='' method='get'>
<select name='select1'>
<?
foreach ($result as $one){    
echo'<option value="'.$one["cat_id"].'">'.$one['cat_name'].'</option>';    
}

?>
</select>    
</form>
```

there is one select tag in test.php
and when i choose a  certain option
another select tag open, which existing in getTest.php

now i want third select tag,,
 when i choose from the second select tag , another one is appear.
i don't know where is that action must done ,, in test.php or in getTest.php

the third select that i want to appear of course is depends on the second select choice,,thanks in advance

Comment: Your sql query is in danger of [sql-injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?s=1|38.9712)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to change your codes like this, In this way you can use millions of selects without any problem.
I commented my changes on your code to better visibility. 
**test.php**

```
<?php
require'models/category.php';
$object=new category;
$rows=$object->display_category();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showUser(str,targetId) {//// add targetId here
  if (str=="") {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="choose a category";
    return;
  } 
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else { // code for IE6, IE5
    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
      document.getElementById(targetId).innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;// this is my added data
      document.getElementById(targetId).style.display = 'block';//update #2
    }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","getTest.php?q="+str,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value,select1)"><!-- add ,1 here -->

<option value="">Select a category:</option>

<?php
foreach($rows as $row){
$row['cat_name']=str_replace('-',' ',$row['cat_name']);

echo'<option value="'.$row['cat_id'].'">'.$row['cat_name'].'</option>';
}
?>
</select>
<!-- This section is added completely -->
<br>
<select id='select1' name='select1' onchange="showUser(this.value,select2)" style="display:none">
</select>
</form>
<br>
<br>
<select id='select2' name='select2' style="display:none">
</select>
</form>
<br>
<!-- End of added section -->
<div id="txtHint"><b>query status will be listed here.</b></div> <!-- category info will not listed here -->
</body>
</html>
```

**getTest.php**

```
<?php
require'models/connection.php';
$q = $_GET['q'];
$level = $_GET['level'];

$query="select * from category where parent_id='".$q."' "; ////DANGER! There is a sql injection vulnerability! Don't do this in your main site never ever

$stmt=$db->prepare($query);

$stmt->execute();
$result=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach ($result as $one){
echo'<option value="'.$one["cat_id"].'">'.$one['cat_name'].'</option>';
}
?>
```

But there is a vulnerability in your sql query that makes your site in danger of sql injection attacks, changing the query code in getTest.php to this one is a good work. but you must check whole your codes with a pentester of course.

**Vulnerable code**

```
$query="select * from category where parent_id='".$q."' ";
$stmt=$db->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
```

must change to this one:

```
$query="select * from category where parent_id=:id ";
$stmt->execute(['id'=>$q]);
```

for more details about this problem, read this post: [How can I prevent SQL-injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: thank you very much ,  i understand your code and it look good,, but it seems that there is a little wrong in the code ,, select tag 1 and 2 that you added ,, i think that must be appear when i choose from first select tag,but there are appear without any choosing

Comment: Ok, I simply added style="display:none" to other selects to hide them, and when Ajax callback occurs, the target select will shows with javascript code.
you know, I answered your question with some sudocodes, and I hope to tell you main idea behind the code, you must update the code to your needs. If you got your answer please let me know with your green check-mark.

Comment: @MohamedMamdouh didn't you find your answer in my solution? If you did, click on correct answer, the gray CHECKMARK under my answer's score.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty same as you done with first one.

First write another function in test.php like you did "showUser" and perform action according to requirement.

Then in getTest.php return html with following.

```
<select name='select1' onchange="showUser(this.value)">
```

So make sure you pass the same function in getTest.php in select that you code newly.